# Invalid left-hand assignment, checking a variable and setting another in a IF statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
if(a=="check" && b=some())
```

The *if* statement will (in theory) return true if `a` is equal to "check" and if `some()` returns something that isn't false/0/null/undefined.

**But this throws an error:** ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment.

In context:

```
function some(){
  return (window.title=="Special")? 0 : window.title;
}
function check(a){
   var b;
   if(a == 1 && b = some()){
      alert("Window's title is: "+b);
   }
}
```

How could I do this **without** using two if statements? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group it with `()`.

```
if( a=="check" && ( b=some() ) )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KsWBq/

This will evaluate the assignment expression, then the result of that expression will be used by the `if()` statement.

Comment: I can't believe it's so simple. Thanks!

Comment: I have to wait 10 minutes to accept the answer, so be patient :)

Comment: @alex: I won't honestly be able to give an in-depth answer as to exactly how the interpreter sees it, but my clumsy explanation is that the `()` allows it to complete the assignment expression and have the result evaluated. Perhaps without the `()` it evaluates `b`, then finds a `=some()` dangling out there alone.

Comment: If you check one variable, the browser expects you to check the other one. So if you only evaluate `if(b = some())` there is no need for extra `()`

Comment: @JCOC611: Yeah, I see it also works if you do `if( a=="check" && b,b = some() ) {`, so I think that's it where it was effectively breaking up the assignment expression by evaluating `b`, then moving on to `= some()`. http://jsfiddle.net/KsWBq/2/

Comment: It's all about the **operator precedence** in the language. Operators "bind" more or less "tightly"; "*" binds more tightly than "+" for example.  The assignment operator is pretty low in the precedence list, and specifically "&&" binds more tightly than "=". [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) is a nice chart of JavaScript operator precedence. (Note that "," is last, which explains why the last couple comments.)

Comment: Thanks @Pointy. Makes sense. So because `,` is last, the `b = some()` is evaluated before the `b`? It's a little confusing since it states that `,` goes left to right. I had assumed it was evaluating `b` then `b = some()`, which was ultimately used for the evaluation.

Comment: ...nevermind. I see [in a test](http://jsfiddle.net/9EQn5/) that it does seem to go left to right.